# How do I link a website thumbnail (Whatsapp and Skype link image)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to change the image of my website that is shown when it is sent on social media (WhatsApp, Discord, Skype, ...).

Examples:

> [image: YES] [image]

I **don't** mean the title icon:

[image: enter NO!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhatsApp uses the `og:image` meta-tag for that Image. 
Add this to your websites `head` element:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/path/to/your/image.png">
```